# Adding a transparent image watermark using WebImage.AddImageWatermark

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, system.web

I'm trying to add a transparent watermark to a series of images using System.Web.Helpers.WebImage.AddImageWatermark, the original image is a .jpg.

I've tried both .gif and .png with transparency but WebImage seems to ignore transparency and treat the transparent background as black. The higher the opacity passed into AddImageWatermark the darker the black.
Is there any way to do this using WebImage?